# Фильтрация строк/поиск по недописанным словам

Tags: c#, .net

Например, есть таблица, которую я выгружаю в массив *(или куда угодно)* `products`:

| products |
| --- |
| Ноутбук Asus Over9999 |
| Ноутбук Dexp T500 |
| Принтер Epson L444 |
| Принтер Canon E7600 |

**Как должен работать поиск:**
Когда в поиск пишешь, например: "*ноут over*", то выводится:

| products |
| --- |
| Ноутбук Asus Over9999 |

А если "*ноут*", то:

| products |
| --- |
| Ноутбук Asus Over9999 |
| Ноутбук Dexp T500 |

В общем, как "Фильтрация строк" в phpMyAdmin.

---

Пробовал делать так:

```
string[] result = { };
string[] keywords = new Regex("\\s+").Replace(textBox1.Text.ToLower(), " ").Trim().Split(' ');

foreach (string keyword in keywords)
{
    result = (from i in products
        where i.ToLower().Contains(keyword)
        select i).ToArray();
}

listBox1.Items.Clear();
listBox1.Items.AddRange(result);
```

Конечно же это не правильно работает, по понятным мне причинам, но ничего лучше не придумал.
Может кто хотя бы подскажет как вообще это должно быть устроено?
Может это должно работать через `Like`?

Comment: `products` - это таблица базы данных или коллекция .NET? Если первое, то какую ORM используете?

Comment: Если вы имеете дело с БД, возможно вам имеет смысл проверить, есть ли в вашей бд поддержка полнотекстового поиска.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте информацию о БД и ORM, нужно знать, с чем именно вы работаете.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov это таблица с БД, которую я выгружаю в массив, но могу вообщем то куда угодно. Мне не нужен поиск по БД, а именно с выгруженными данными.

Comment: Можно наверное сделать `result = products.ToArray()` перед циклом, а внутри делать выборку не из `products`, а из `result` (и обратно в `result`), тогда после прохода цикла в `result` останутся только продукты, в которых есть каждое слово из поисковой строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, хотя, наверное, есть решение оптимальнее:

```
result = products; // .ToArray() то ли нужен, то ли нет
foreach (string keyword in keywords)
{
    result = (from i in result // именно in result, а не in products
        where i.ToLower().Contains(keyword)
        select i).ToArray();
}
```

После прохода цикла в `result` должны остаться только продукты, в которых есть каждое слово из поисковой строки.

Comment: Это отлично работает, в `products` не будет много записей, поэтому мне этого вполне достаточно. Благодарю.